# Redirect to another page after CURL POST

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I can't figure out how to redirect after CURL executing. I found something like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
```

But I need something like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AFTER_SUCCESS_GO_TO, "http://anotherpage.com");
```

Comment: And it has to be done in cURL? Have you tried [header](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)?

Comment: What is your goal here? What are you trying to do? Do you want to redirect the user after you've made a curl post?

Comment: Something like that

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` if you want curl to automatically follow a "redirect" (which is a 3XX response and a `Location:` response header).

If you just want to fetch another URL after the first request succeeds, then just issue another one...